# Should I .gitignore Application/build/ folder in AndroidStudio?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, gitignore

I know that I have to `.gitignore` the `/build` folder in project root. But there is also `Application/build/` folder. Do i need to track it?

Update: I see there is another similar question but more general. But I don't see anyone there talking about issue like I have. It looks like if you put slash at the end it makes the difference: `build/`

And it looks like nobody talks there about Application/build folder. This must be new project structure because some people use /builder and it works for them. That's because they don't have Application/builder folder. I think.

Comment: I'm not in front of Android Studio at the moment, but if `Application/build` contains build artifacts then yes, you probably should be ignoring it too.

Comment: `/build` is only files and folders in the project root. `/build/` is only folders in the root. `build/` is all folders. `build` is all files and folders. https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A typical [AndroidStudio gitignore file](https://www.gitignore.io/api/androidstudio) does include the gitignore rule

```
build/
```

That would ignore *any* build folder, recursively from the top folder of the repository.
Including  `Application/build`.

Comment: it worked for me thanks. I had it like this /build and this worked only for root. When changed to build/ it worked recursively.

Comment: I can't vote yet need to get those 15 creds :)

Comment: ok gotcha, done.